Inline Attachments Broke In Legacy Outlook For Mac
When I get html body with Office.js Api in Legacy Outlook inline attachments are look like this
<p class="MsoNormal"><span lang="TR" style='font-size:11.0pt;color:black'><img border="0" width="341" height="77" style='width:3.552in;height:.802in' id="Picture 6" src="~WRS%7b4E9DED9C-A15B-5149-A002-13DDAC7F3D02%7d.fld/image001.jpg" style='height:.802in;width:3.552in' alt="Image"></span></p>

But when I get html body with Office.js Api in New Outlook inline attachments are look like this
<span lang="TR" style='font-size:11.0pt;mso-bidi-font-family:Calibri;color:black;mso-ansi-language:TR'><span style='mso-no-proof:yes'><img border="0" width="341" height="77" id="Picture_x0020_6" src="cid:image001.png@01DAE365.F0D05C80" alt="Image"></span></span>

and if i change outlook with even same body inline attachments are getting broked
broken image => image
how can i change body without broke images in legacy outlook ?
 Office.context.mailbox.item.body.setAsync(htmlBody)

I am using this code same in legacy outlook and new outlook for mac but it hink problem is with the html body because its diffirent
